# Typescript find type of union type

Tags: typescript, types

I want to know the type `c` in `printTypeOf` function.
Here is my code:

```
type Email ={
    email:string,
}
type Phone ={
    phone:string,
}
type ContactInfo = Email | Phone;

function printTypeOf(c: ContactInfo) {
    console.log(typeof c)
}

const x: Email = { email: "X" };
printTypeOf(x);
```

Current output is `object` but I need to find if it is `Email` or `Phone`

Answer (score 1):

You can't print a name of a type because once TypeScript is transpiled to JavaScript all the type information is lost. It prints `object` because that's what the TypeScript turns into once you have running code.

Comment: how can I find the type in my function?

Comment: The [handbook's "Advanced Types" section](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types) probably has the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot print the type, as the type doesnt exists in the runtime. Only type representation exists at this point, and in your case representation of let say `Email` is an object `{ email: string}`. That really everything you got.

`typeof` operator will only output string in form of primary types names [typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof).So it is not possible that this operator will give you any clue about custom type.

In order to differential the structures in the runtime, they need to be different ( what a discovery :) ). Already they are, as one has `email` and second has `phone`. These props are enough to do conditions and check, as other answers are saying to do. But better is to create special property, discriminant [discriminant in tagged union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union). Such kind of special property gives you possibility to:

- apply custom logic by checking it
- have clear difference between type representations in the runtime

In below code such discriminant has a form of `_type` property, but you can choose whatever has a sense for you.

```
  type Email = {
    email: string,
    _type: 'Email' // discriminant
  }

  const makeEmail = (email: string): Email => ({
    email,
    _type: 'Email'
  }); // value constructor, very handy for DRY

  type Phone = {
    phone: string,
    _type: 'Phone' // discriminant
  }

  const makePhone = (phone: string): Phone => ({
    phone,
    _type: 'Phone'
  }); // value constructor, very handy for DRY


  type ContactInfo = Email | Phone;

  function printTypeOf(c: ContactInfo) {
    console.log(c._type); // we log discriminant
  }

  const email = makeEmail('X');
  const phone = makePhone('99');
  printTypeOf(email); // logs Email
  printTypeOf(phone); // logs Phone
```

Answer (score 0):

```
type Email ={
    email: string,
    type: 'email',
}
type Phone ={
    phone: string,
    type: 'phone'
}
type ContactInfo = Email | Phone;

function printTypeOf(c: ContactInfo) {
    console.log(c.type); // 'email' or 'phone' 
    switch (c.type) { 
        case 'email':
            console.log(c.email);
            break;
        case 'phone':
            console.log(c.phone);
    }
}
```

just add type information. but you will ahve define it in initialize of that type:

```
const contactInfo: ContactInfo = {
    type: 'email',
    email: 'email'
}
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=25&ssc=2&pln=22&pc=1#code/AQ4FwTwBwU2BRAtgQwJYBtgF4DeBYAKFGOBhQwC5gBnMAJ1QDsBzAGkJNElioHIy06XuyKgAvhy7Q4ABQAWAe0ZxckzlEXKqtBixGcQ3GHw1KYvNcAmjD04AGElYZAGMwASUYAzBdgTlMAB9geTMAbktLLwBXRjdUJWAoXTAAFWkAeS8AChcqR0ZnN08fAEpgfBsSFyVqBXQYADp0BWZcxqNSiKriagB3VDAXOWB2zorgSwNgF2RqOH4A3gop6dAaxjqG5tb2gQwu1bXgACM6GGQAa27jkFn54F5TZWWjtY2tppa2l0bnmEOPXEhGshA%20YBmTlcHm8CnyUOKsL8lWIRj4%20yE%20lAGPRSxBQA)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can do something like this,

```
function printTypeOf(c: ContactInfo) {
    if(c.hasOwnProperty('email')){
        console.log('email');
    } else if(c.hasOwnProperty('phone')){
        console.log('phone');
    }
}
```